Variables in ffmpeg
I'm trying to do a basic batch script for create video titles in movie files (*.ts) but it doesn't work when adding SET variable.
@for /r %%F in (*.ts) do (
echo %%~nxF
set /P moviename=NEW VIDEO NAME:
"c:\program files\ffmpeg" -y -i "%%F" -map 0 -c copy -metadata title="%moviename%" "%%~pnF.mp4" 2>> output.log
)


This is a batch scripting 'gotcha'. Due to the way cmd.exe expands variables, if you use SET with parenthesis blocks (such as FOR, IF etc) you need to
(1) have this line somewhere in the batch script before the start of the block:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(2) AND ALSO any variable that you SET in the block and wish to use in that block needs to use exclamation marks/points and not percent signs
like this
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%F in (*.ts) do (
    echo %%~nxF
    set /P moviename=NEW VIDEO NAME:
    "c:\program files\ffmpeg" -y -i "%%F" -map 0 -c copy -metadata title="!moviename!" "%%~pnF.mp4" 2>> output.log
)

